# html load external url favicons

Tags: javascript, html, favicon

is there a way how to automatically load favicons from external websites inside html format? Maybe specific javascript which search and copy favicon path a put them inside "img".

If you have list of URLs its very problematic found favicon for every site and maintain them working.

And if there non such complex javasript, then maybe another simple one which just take "a href" url and put them with "favicon.ico" at the end inside "img" part... :) this will not work with every url, but at least something.

thanks

example:

```
<div class=web>
<a href="https://web1.com/"><img src="https://web1.com/favicon.ico">WEB1.com</a>
<a href="https://web2.com/"><img src="https://web2.com/favicon.ico">WEB2.com</a>
...
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you need favicon inside an img tag instead of link tag?

Comment: You would need to convert the .ico to base64 before you append it to img element.

Comment: I think the problem is that ico files fan be named differently. So You should basically have not only website URLs but also exact URLs for ico files. Then it would just work in that way it is used in provided example.

Answer (score 3):

Google has an API to do just this. Just append the targeted domain to Google API URL, like `https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.org`.

So your example becomes:

```
<div class=web>
  <a href="https://web1.com/"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=web1.com">WEB1.com</a>
  <a href="https://web2.com/"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=web2.com">WEB2.com</a>
  ...
</div>
```